# Sending Email in Asp.net by private email

Tags: asp.net, sendmail

I'm trying to send email from my website i have these settings in my webconfig

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="info@thtsa.com">

      <network host="smtp.privateemail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" userName="info@thtsa.com" password="*****" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

but this exception

```
InnerException = {"The remote name could not be resolved: 'info@thtsa.com'"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when your code is not able to access your mail server. Please check if your server where your application is installed has access to your email server. You may try to ping to email server from your application server.

Additionally, you can try to use IP of smtp server instead of mail server name.